# What's the meaning of the tshark output fields?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

Dear wireshark experts,

I got a tshark output image on *ubuntu 16.04* after I ran the command `curl www.baidu.com`, as shown below. But I can't tell you the story from the output lines, because I can't find any mathematical relationships betweens the lines.

Could someone explain the meaning of each line, especially the field **Ack** and **Win**?

So appreciated in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not related to tshark/wireshark, but generally to TCP protocol:

- `ACK` (and `SYN`) are tcp flags being set during [connection establishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)
- `Win` is also tcp parameter. see [Window size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)

Comment: Thanks. I've read through the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793), and now I understand how to establish and close a TCP connection. But what about `Len` from line 5 to 9, it is always 0. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

FrameNumber Timestamp Source-IP-Address -> Destination-IP-Address Protocol TCP-Source-Port TCP-Destination-Port [TCP-FLAGS] Protocol-Specific-Description

SYN/ACK/WIN are related to the [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) protocol which is used for reliable transmission on top of the unreliable IP network